# Combining orWhere and where in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM AS T
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.id =T2.tid
WHERE (t1.userid= $userid AND t1.unitid IN (2,3))
    OR (t2.requesterid=$userid AND      t2.requestertype IN(1,5))
```

With raw query in Laravel I could do:

```
DB::table("TABLE1 as T1")
->join("TABLE2 as T2", "T1.userttype", " =","T2.tid")
->whereRaw("(t1.userid= $userid AND t1.unitid IN     (2,3)) OR (t2.requesterid=$userid AND t2.requestertype IN(1,5)")->get();
```

But how can this be achieved by Laravel orWhere structure. I tried it as :

```
DB::table("TABLE1 as T1")
  ->join("TABLE2 as T2", "T1.userttype", "=", "T2.tid")
  ->where(function($query) use ($userid) {
         $query->where("t1.userid", $userid)
               ->whereIn("t1.unitid", [2,3])
               ->orwhere("t2.requesterid", $userid)
               ->whereIn("t2.requestertype", [1,5])
  });
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try two inner functions. Try this:

```
DB::table("TABLE1 as T1")
->join("TABLE2 as T2", "T1.userttype", "=", "T2.tid")
->where(function($query) use ($userid) {
       $query->where("t1.userid", $userid)
             ->whereIn("t1.unitid", [2,3]);
})->orWhere(function($query) use ($userid) {
       $query->where("t2.requesterid", $userid)
             ->whereIn("t2.requestertype", [1,5]);
});
```